# How will the race I pick affect quests and skills?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages/disadvantages of each race?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34981/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-each-race)

So I really need to get into this game, but I want to know if the race I pick will affect any quests/skills or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Each race has 1-3 unique abilities, a +10 bonus to one skill, and a +5 bonus to five other skills.

Specific skills and abilities for each race are already covered in this question:
[What are the advantages/disadvantages of each race?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34981/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-each-race)

The only other thing your race will affect is appearance, height of the 1st person camera,  and minor dialogue. (khajiit and argonian players will receive the most racism.)

Comment: Racism? As a Khajiit, bandits are always telling me how nice of a rug I would make. I take that as a compliment!